# Are there two or more editions of the Rambam's Peirush HaMishnayos?

Tags: rambam, commentaries, mishna, publications

I heard that there are differences between the Rambam's Peirush Hamishnayos found most commonly in the Mishnayos Zecher Chanoch and the version found in Mishnayos which are paired with the Rash. Is this true?

Additionally I am aware that there is an edition made by Rabbi Kafech of the Rambam's Peirush. Is it any different from the other two listed above?

Comment: Those are all just different translations.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the question is whether they are translating from different editions of the original.

Comment: @DoubleAA actually, I know of one case (Peah 6:3 or 6:4, the ראשי שורות discussion) where there's a completely different _picture_ in the back of the Gemara vs. R' Kapach's translation.  R' Kapach's translation matches the picture in his version.  The text of the Rambam in the Gemara is hard to follow so I can't really tell if it matches the picture there.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Yosef Kappach made a great work translating the manuscripts of the Rambam in modern hebrew. His translation was critiqued by some people, I don't know what are the points critiqued because of his preference for one of the manuscripts. Rav Kapah expressed sharp criticism of the medieval translations. Rav Guedalia Nadel was thinking that the work of Rav Kapah contains a lot of errors in understanding the Rambam  (oral sources).

Rabbi Shilat works more than 20 years on translation of parts of the perush hamishna in a medieval scholastic like Hebrew.

There is also the new translation from the Rav Ezra Korach,  in [machon Hamaor](http://www.sefer.org.il/m/Product.aspx?ProductID=40526)  which was approved by [Rav Steinman and Rav Eliashiv and Rav Shmuel Auerbach.](https://www.google.co.il/amp/www.kikar.co.il/amp/591?client=ms-android-gionee).  This translation contains a great amount of notes.  The Korah family is linked to Kapah family and both were in Yemen,  In Wikipedia you can find [Yosef Korah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97), Shalom Korah, [Pinchas Korah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A1_%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97), who translated the sefer Hamitsvot, but not Ezra Korah. (I'm not sure)

Zecher Chanoch is the same as the perush HaRamban in shas Vilna but many typo were corrected. See in Kappach introduction,  there are many authors.

Comment: `I don't know what are the points critiqued because of his preference for one of the manuscripts.` This sentence is fairly convoluted. Do you mean that you don't know why R. Qafih preferred Rambam's own handwritten copy of PHM to other copies? That this is the reason you don't know what the critiques are? Consider revising. | Why are you talking about R. Shilat? Did he author an edition? If so consider mentioning it in your answer.

Comment: `The Korah family is linked to Kapah family and both were in Yemen` What is your source that they are linked? What do you mean by linked? Why is it relevant?

Comment: `which was approved by Rav Steinman and Rav Eliashiv and Rav Shmuel Auerbach.` AFAIK none of them speak medieval Judeo-Arabic, so why is this relevant?

Comment: Note that R. Qorah largely copies (plagarises) R. Qafih's translation, see here: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2014/06/assorted-comments.html.

Comment: @mevaqesh for some people it is relevant. sorry

Comment: @mevaqesh you are saying about plagiarism may be you are right. I found an edition of PHM. You want to prohibit to say that there is an other edition?  You make censorship?

Comment: rav Nadel studied the PHM and concluded that the translation of rav Kapah has many errors.  I personally am not able to judge anything but I wanted just to show that the translation of RK is not for  unanimity the  ultimate

Comment: `His translation was critiqued by some people...Rav Guedalia Nadel was thinking [sic] that the work of Rav Kapah contains a lot of errors in understanding the Rambam (oral sources). ` First you say that there are issues in his translation, then you reference issues in understanding. In comments, you stated that R. Nadel had an opinion about PHM, in the post you state the opinion was about his "works" in general. Consider clarifying what exactly you heard. Consider also clarifying what it was that you heard. | Consider also clarifying from who you heard this. Was it second hand? Third? Etc.

Comment: @mevaqesh you think that I need to say from who I heard...  perhaps I heard myself. but I don't want to cite strong words of criticism because I am a moderate person and the strict necessity is to point that some great TC did depreciate the PHM Kapah edition.  I am not a part of the discussion, I am a very little student. So I don't want to express the issue as if I had a personal opinion

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the two editions in the top of your question, however, the R' Yusuf Kafiẖ זצ”ל [edition](https://www.mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%9D/) follows the original manuscript of the Rambam's peirush in the author's own hand. See the copyright information in the front of his edition.

Comment: Note that that mori qafih didn't have rambams manuscript to the whole perush hamishna, e.g. nezikin.

Comment: @mevaqesh, I'm only following the copyright info, which specifies that it follows the Rambam's k'tav yad

Comment: Was that for the whole thing or a particular volume? Did you read the introduction?

Comment: @mevaqesh, I looked on the title page the Zeraim/Mo'ed volume.

Comment: Then it might be a mistake to generalise about the rest of the PHM.